# UIScrollView Changing Position Between Devices

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios6

I have a UIScrollView that has a number of UILabels and UITextViews inside it. When I switch between devices in the simulator all the surrounding elements stay in the correct place but the UIScrollView moves down the screen and out of position.

It occurs when switching between 3.5 and 4 inch devices. Aay idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check its autosizing settings in the Size Inspector tab in Interface Builder.

Comment: Thanks, I have been trying all sorts in IB to try and get the layout correct. I thought it was something to do with the Auto Layout option.